# Are there any functions $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ whose Taylor series do not exist on $I$ even if $f$ is infinitely differentiable on $I$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion, sequence-of-function

Let $$T[f(x),a]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(a)\,(x-a)^n}{n!}$$ given that $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, that $I\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, that $a\in I$, and that $f^{(n)}(a)$ exists for all $n\in\mathbb{N\cup\{0\}}$.

Does there exist some function $f$ such that $T[f(x),a]$ **does not exist** on $I$?

Remember that $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$, note that it is possible for $I$ to include or not include numbers that have imaginary parts, and note that functions $f:f(x)\neq T[f(x),a]$ **are irrelevant** if $T[f(x),a]$ is defined.

---

**Edit 21 August 2017**

After heavy consideration, I think this boils down to whether or not there exists a function such that $f^{(n)}(a)\ge n!$ as $n\to\infty$.

---

**Edit 3 September 2017**

I have been considering the function $\Pi(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$. You can find a discussion about the very nasty $n$<sup>th</sup> derivative [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399842/i-ran-fracdndxnx-through-the-calculator-but-don-t-understand-the). I did, however, run a graph of it through the web graphing calculator [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nuy5ngb0lz). Basically, each higher bar is a higher derivative of $\Pi(x)$, and it spans the positive interval on which $\Pi^{(n)}(x)\ge n!$

[image: Desmos]

Once I got to $\Pi^{(4)}(x)$, it started crashing, which is why the purple bar is incomplete (if it were meant to stop around $x=5.3$, then there would be a bold vertical line).

To me, this small sample seems to suggest that $\Pi^{(n)}(a)\ge n!$ for $a$ at least greater than or equal to $2$, which would make the coefficients of $T[\Pi(x),a]$ all be greater than or equal to $1$, so $T[\Pi(x),a]$ would diverge.

---

Comment: If a function has all derivatives at a point, its Taylor series exists. What may happen es that the series does not converge to the function.

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$, you want [Borel's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63050/every-power-series-is-the-taylor-series-of-some-c-infty-function). I don't understand completely the complex part of your question. Obviously you don't mean that $I$ can be an open set in $\mathbb{C}$ and that differentiability means that $f$ is holomorphic in $I$. If you only mean that $f$ is a $C^\infty$ function of 2 variables, then the Taylor series has a more complicated form.

Comment: @Gribouillis Interesting. I mostly included $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$ to learn something new. I'll have to read about this “more complicated form”!

Answer (score 1):

Consider first $g: \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$,
$$
g(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
\mathrm{e}^{-1/x^2} & \text{if $x>0$},\\
0 & \text{otherwise.} 
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Then $g\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$, and $f^{(n)}(0)=0$, for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Thus the Taylor series
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{g^{(n)}(0)\,x^n}{n!}
$
exists but $g(x)\ne\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{g^{(n)}(0)\,x^n}{n!}$, for $x>0$.

Using this example, you can create similar situations for functions $f: \mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, when all partial derivatives in $x$ and $y$ exists.

Comment: That’s nice, but I'm looking for functions where the Taylor series *doesn’t* exist… I don't really care if it converges to the original function either…

Comment: Also, what is $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$? I assume it's a set of functions that map $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor If all the derivatives of $f$ exists, then so does the Taylor series. What do you mean *the Taylor series doesn't exist*?

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't converge at a certain point