# I ran $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}[(x!)!]$ through the calculator but don’t understand the $R^{(0,1)}$ and $R(n,x)$ in the output

Tags: calculus, derivatives, factorial, gamma-function, polygamma

I ran $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}[(x!)!]$ through *[Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nth%20derivative%20of%20(x!)!)*, which returned

> $$\frac{\partial^n(x!)!}{\partial x^n} = \Gamma(1+x!)\,R(n,1+x!)$$
>   for
>
> - $R(n,x)=\psi(x)\,R(-1+n,x)+R^{(0,1)}(-1+n,x)$
> - $R(0,x)=1$
> - $n\in\mathbb{Z}$
> - $n>0$
>
> where $\psi^{(n)}(x)$ is the $n$<sup>th</sup> derivative of the digamma function

They define the [polygamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygammaFunction.html) as $$\psi^{(n)}(x)=\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}\ln[\Gamma(x)]$$

What on Earth is $R^{(0,1)}$, and how can I make sense of this $R(n,x)$ business?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f_n(x)$ as follows and show that$$f_n(x)=\Gamma(x)R(n,x)=\frac d{dx}\Gamma(x)R(n-1,x)=f'_{n-1}(x)\\f_0(x)=\Gamma(x)$$

From this, you can see that we actually have

$$f_n(x)=\Gamma^{(n)}(x)$$

And particularly,

> $$R(n,x)=\frac{f_n(x)}{\Gamma(x)}=\frac{\Gamma^{(n)}(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$$

Comment: Perfect answer. I've never un-selected someone's answer, but I this time I did.

Comment: Well, do as you may as you need, and glad to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

The superscript notation means (I think) the derivative: $$R^{(0,1)}(−1+n,x)=\frac{\partial R(n,x)}{\partial x}\Bigr|_{(−1+n,x)}$$

$R(n,x)$ is so ugly, it seems, that it cannot be expressed in some closed form but only as a recursion in $n$:

$$R(n,x)=\frac{d \ln[\Gamma(x)]}{dx} \,R(-1+n,x)+\frac{\partial R(n,x)}{\partial x}\Bigr|_{(−1+n,x)}$$

Comment: So when you say “cannot,” do you mean it is ***literally*** impossible?

Comment: That word in bold doesn't mean anything, unless you define exactly what we mean by "closed form". See eg https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral

Comment: Your interpretation of the superscript notation is indeed correct as far as WA goes.

Comment: Interestingly, $R(n,x)$ is not so ugly if you allow $\Gamma^{(n)}(x)$ in it. However, $\Gamma^{(n)}(x)$ cannot be written nicely in terms of polygamma functions, which is somewhat unfortunate.