# Confusion between power series and taylor series

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

Given some power series $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n$, is it generally true that $a_n = \frac{f^{(n)}}{n!}$? If so, why? We get this form when we develop a taylor series, but why is this case for every power series? Can't the $a_n$ terms be arbitrary? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: You have to show that power series reps are unique.  Since the Taylor form is one, it must be the one.

Comment: See Matt E's answer on the question I've linked. In a nutshell, I would phrase the difference as: power series are from the perspective of the *series*, which has a corresponding function but Taylor series are from the perspective of the *function*, which has a corresponding series. If the series is convergent, they're the same thing. If the series [isn't *necessarily* convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series) (i.e., it's just a list of coefficients), it's no longer a Taylor series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since$$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots,$$you have $f(0)=a_0$ and $$f'(x)=a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+\cdots\tag1$$and therefore $f'(0)=a_1$. On the other hand, since you have $(1)$, you have$$f''(x)=2a_2+6a_3x+12a_4x^2+\cdots$$and, in particular, $f''(0)=2a_2$ and so on…

Answer (score 1):

If the series
$$
f(x)=\sum_na_nx^n
$$
converges in some neighborhood of zero, then $a_n=f^{(n)}(0)/n!$.  This follows from term-by-term differentiation (which in turn follows form uniform convergence of power series inside the radius of convergence).

It is a fact that any sequence of real numbers $a_n$ are the Taylor coefficients of some function, i.e. there exists some $f$ with $f^{(n)}(0)=n!a_n$; however, the Taylor series doesn't necessarily converge (or converge to $f$).  This goes by the name "Borel's lemma" in various places.  See this post (and the monthly article giving Peano's earlier constructive proof) [Every power series is the Taylor series of some $C^{\infty}$ function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63050/every-power-series-is-the-taylor-series-of-some-c-infty-function).