Maclaurin series with zero radius of convergence
Does there exist a smooth function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ whose Maclaurin series has a zero radius of convergence? In other words, does there exist a smooth function such that the Maclaurin series
$P_n(x):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$
for $f(x)$ satisfies the property that
$
\lim_{n \to \infty} P_n(x) = \infty
$ for all $x \neq 0$, where
$a_n=\frac{f^n(0)}{n!}$
is the $n$-th partial sum of the series? If not why so?
P.S: The function $ f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$ is not the candidate here, because it has a Maclaurin series that converges to zero for all $ x$, (though not to $f(x)$)

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63050/every-power-series-is-the-taylor-series-of-some-c-infty-function for example.

The result directly follows from Borel's theorem, but one explicit example is the function
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-n}\cos(n^2x) $$
as found in Gelbaum's Counterexamples in Analysis, pp68-70. One can check that all derivatives converge for all $x$, and that all series coefficients exceed $1$ for large enough degree.
