# $ \sum_{l=1}^n(-1)^{l-1}\binom{n}{l}\sum_{k=0}^{l-1}\binom{l-1}{k}b_k = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k b_k \,. $

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Today I encountered the following identity during some work: letting $b_k$ be a sequence,
$$
\sum_{l=1}^n(-1)^{l-1}\binom{n}{l}\sum_{k=0}^{l-1}\binom{l-1}{k}b_k = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k b_k \,.
$$
I've struggled for a while with properties of binomial coefficients and induction strategies, then I think I found a proof using derivatives (see below). 
Are there more conventional/straightforward proofs?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is a way by direct manipulation of the binomials.
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{l = 1}^n {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l - 1} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  l \cr}  \right)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{l - 1} {\left( \matrix{
  l - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)b_{\,k} } }  =   \quad \quad (1) \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,l\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,l - 1} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l - 1} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  l \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  l - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)b_{\,k} } }  =  \quad \quad (2)  \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,l\,\left( { \le \,n - 1} \right)} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,l} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  l + 1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  l \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)b_{\,k} } }  =  \quad \quad (3)  \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,l\,\left( { \le \,n - 1} \right)} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,l} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  l + 1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  l \cr 
  l - k \cr}  \right)b_{\,k} } }  =  \quad \quad (4)  \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,l\,\left( { \le \,n - 1} \right)} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,l} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  l + 1 \cr}  \right)\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l - k} \left( \matrix{
   - k - 1 \cr 
  l - k \cr}  \right)b_{\,k} } }  =  \quad \quad (5)  \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,l} \right)} {\left( {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,l\,\left( { \le \,n - 1} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  l + 1 \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
   - k - 1 \cr 
  l - k \cr}  \right)} } \right)\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} b_{\,k} }  =  \quad \quad (6)  \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,l} \right)} {\left( {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,l\,\left( { \le \,n - 1} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  n - 1 - l \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
   - k - 1 \cr 
  l - k \cr}  \right)} } \right)\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} b_{\,k} } \quad \left| {\;0 \le n} \right.\quad  =  \quad \quad (7)  \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n - 1} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  n - k - 1 \cr 
  n - k - 1 \cr}  \right)\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} b_{\,k} } \quad \left| {\;0 \le n} \right.\quad  =   \quad \quad (8) \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} b_{\,k} } \quad \left| {\;1 \le n} \right.  \quad \quad (9) \cr} 
}$$

where:
 (1) original expression;
 (2) we get rid (put in brackets) of the summation bounds
which are implicit in the binomial;
 (3) we change $l$ with $l-1$;
 (4) since $0 \le l$ we can apply symmetry and get rid
also of the lower bound on $l$;
 (5) *Upper Negation*;
 (6) exchange order of summation;
 (7) symmetry on the first binomial, provided that $0 \le n$;
 (8) bounds allow to apply convolution in $l$;
 (9) the binomial provides the bounds on summation

Concerning the approach you propose, it looks "formally" pretty valid.
I am hesitant from a rigorous point of view when it comes  to take the multiplicative inverse, but I am not a *theorist*.

However, yours parallels a slight different approach that I would take, based on the *Right Shift Operator*, 
which I know is valid also from a rigorous point of view.

$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
E\,f(x) = f(x + 1)\quad E\;b_{\,k}  = b_{\,k + 1} \quad b_{\,k}  = E^{\,k} \;b_{\,0} 
} $$
Then
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
\eqalign{
  & LHS = \sum\limits_{l = 1}^n {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l - 1} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  l \cr}  \right)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{l - 1} {\left( \matrix{
  l - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)b_{\,k} } }  = \sum\limits_{l = 1}^n {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l - 1} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  l \cr}  \right)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{l - 1} {\left( \matrix{
  l - 1 \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)E^{\,k} \;b_{\,0} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = b_{\,0} \sum\limits_{l = 1}^n {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l - 1} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  l \cr}  \right)\left( {I + E} \right)^{\,l - 1} }  =  - {{b_{\,0} } \over {\left( {I + E} \right)}}\sum\limits_{l = 1}^n {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,l} \left( \matrix{
  n \cr 
  l \cr}  \right)\left( {I + E} \right)^{\,l} }  =   \cr 
  &  =  - {{b_{\,0} } \over {\left( {I + E} \right)}}\left( {\left( {I - \left( {I + E} \right)} \right)^{\,n}  - I} \right) =  - b_{\,0} {{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} E^{\,n}  - I} \over {\left( {I + E} \right)}} = b_{\,0} {{I - \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} E^{\,n} } \over {\left( {I + E} \right)}} \cr} 
} $$
and
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {  
RHS = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} b_{\,k} }  = b_{\,0} \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,n - 1} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} E^{\,k} }  = b_{\,0} {{I - \left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} E^{\,n} } \over {I + E}}
} $$

Comment: Your argument is very nice: the RSO coincides with the derivative when $b_k=\partial^k f$, so I guess this makes it rigorous. Thanks!

Comment: Well, then instead of a "function" f(x), which would imply problems of convergence for some $b_k$ sequences, I guess you should talk of a "formal power series".

Comment: @G Cab What convergence issues are you referring to? I am just using the fact that every sequence is the sequence of derivatives of some smooth (but not necessarily analytic) function https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/every-real-sequence-is-the-derivative-sequence-of-some-function

Comment: @Brightsun: if, e.g., $b_k=(k!)^2$, then what "smooth function" will correspond to it ?

Comment: As far as I know the function is not unique, but nonetheless it exists: it's a result due to Borel (see the link in my previous comment). @G Cab

Comment: @Brightsun: Uhm, I did not know that power series with a null convergence radius can still be named functions. But as I said I am not a theorist, so I am going to accept that.

Comment: @G Cab Indeed they cannot. The claim by Borel is that, given *any* sequence $b_k$, then one can find a function $f(x)$ such that $b_k=\partial^k f$, but it does not claim that $f(x)=\sum_k b_k x^k/k!$, in general. The latter is true only for those $b_k$ for which the series converges, as you correctly pointed out, and then the result is trivial.

Comment: Thanks, now I got better understanding of "Borel's claim". However, it seems to me that it would be less troublesome to found your claim onto "formal power series", or .. is it not?

Comment: @G Cab A formal power series does not define a function. The Borel's theorem ensures you can find a function with the above property.

Comment: @G Cab Also, $b_k=(k!)^2=\partial^k f$ is satisfied by $f(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-t}/(1-xt)dt$, defined for $x<0$.

Answer (score 1):

We start from

$$\sum_{l=1}^n (-1)^{l-1} {n\choose l}
\sum_{k=0}^{l-1} {l-1\choose k} b_k
= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} b_k
\sum_{l=k+1}^n {n\choose l} (-1)^{l-1} {l-1\choose k}.$$

We get for the coefficient on $b_k$

$$\sum_{l=k+1}^n {n\choose l} (-1)^{l-1} {l-1\choose k}
= \sum_{l=k}^{n-1} {n\choose l+1} (-1)^l {l\choose k}
\\ = \sum_{l=k}^{n-1} {n\choose l+1} (-1)^l [z^k] (1+z)^l.$$

We may  start $l$ at zero  because $[z^k] (1+z)^l$ is  zero when $0\le
l\lt k$, getting

$$[z^k] \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} {n\choose l+1} (-1)^l (1+z)^l
= - [z^k] \frac{1}{1+z}
\sum_{l=0}^{n-1} {n\choose l+1} (-1)^{l+1} (1+z)^{l+1}
\\ = - [z^k] \frac{1}{1+z}
\left((1-(1+z))^n - 1\right)
= [z^k] \frac{(-1)^{n+1} z^n}{1+z} + [z^k] \frac{1}{1+z}.$$

Note however that $n\gt k$ so there is no contribution from
the first term and we are left with

$$[z^k] \frac{1}{1+z} = (-1)^k$$

as claimed.

Comment: This method entails essentially the same cancellations as mine (especially the resummation which gives $(1-1-z)^n-1$) but from the perspective of the $[z^k]$ operator. I am only not really sure of why you got rid of $b_k$ all over the place...?

Comment: Well on the first line the inner sum is the coefficient on $b_k$ so if we can prove it is $(-1)^k$ we have the claim independent of the values $b_k$ actually takes.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I missed that step! @Marko Riedel

Answer (score 0):

For a given sequence $b_k$, by Borel's lemma (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/every-real-sequence-is-the-derivative-sequence-of-some-function) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%27s_lemma)), there exists a function $f(x)$ such that
$
b_k = f^{(k)}(0) \equiv \partial^kf.
$
Thus we need only prove
$$
\sum_{l=1}^n(-1)^{l-1}\binom{n}{l}\sum_{k=0}^{l-1}\binom{l-1}{k}\partial^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k \partial^k\,.
$$
The right-hand side can be evaluated formally using $1-x+x^2+\cdots+(-x)^{n-1}=(1-(-x)^n)/(1+x)$, and yields
$$
\frac{1-(-\partial)^n}{1+\partial}\,.
$$
The left-hand side can be manipulated using Newton's binomial formula, giving
$$
\sum_{l=1}^n(-1)^{l-1}\binom{n}{l}(1+\partial)^{l-1}=\frac{1}{-1-\partial}\sum_{l=1}^n\binom{n}{l}(-1-\partial)^l=\frac{(1-1-\partial)^n-1}{-1-\partial}=\frac{1-(-\partial)^n}{1+\partial}\,.
$$